# Codeigniter validation library store errors in session

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, session

I am making use of the validation library provided by Codeigniter.
My web application uses sessions and javascript to populate alert message.
Therefore, I want my error message to be in json format.
But the helper function validation_errors() only output html format.
What can I do?

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
            {
                add_flash_message('alert', $flash_in_json);
                redirect('enquiry/create');
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gues right solution is extend CI_Form_valuidation class to add getter to protected  varible $_error_array..

```
Class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {
   function getErrorsArray(
       return $this->$_error_array;
   )
}
```

Comment: +1 for using the error array. To add to this, the format of the items in the array is `'field name' => 'Error message'`. You can convert it to json with json_encode(). Keep in mind that there can be more than one error, so you may need to wrap add_flash_message() in a foreach loop or modify it to accept the array rather than a single error.

Answer (score 1):

this is a function for converting the `validation_errors()` output to json

```
function prep_validation_errors($errors){
        $str = str_replace('</p>', '', $errors);
        $arr = explode('<p>', $str);
        return json_encode($arr);
    }
```

then you can use it as the following:

```
$json = $this->prep_validation_errors(validation_errors());
```